# Not able to read Configuration file Using scala typesafe API

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark/scala project named as Omega

I have a conf file inside Omega/conf/omega.config

I use API's from typesafe to load the config file from  conf/omega.config.
It was working fine and I was able to read the respective value for each key

Now today, For the first time I added some more key-value pairs in my omega.config file and tried to retrieve them from my scala code. It throws

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'job_name'
```

This issue started happening after adding new value for the key job_name in my omega.config file. 
Also I am not able to read the newly added -key-values, I am still able to read all old values using config. getString method

I am building my spark/scala application using maven.

Omega.config

```
input_path="/user/cloudera/data
user_name="surender"
job_name="SAMPLE"
```

I am Not able to access the recently added key "job_name" alone 
   package com.pack1

```
import com.pack2.ApplicationUtil
object OmegaMain {

  val config_loc = "conf/omega.config"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val config               = ApplicationUtil.loadConfig(config_loc)
   val jobName              = ApplicationUtil.getFromConfig(config,"job_name")
}
}


package com.pack2
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}


object ApplicationUtil {

 def loadConfig(filePath:String):Config={
  val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(filePath))

  config
 }

  def getFromConfig(config:Config,jobName:String):String={
    config.getString(jobName)
  }

}
```

Could some one help me what went wrong?

Comment: Do you resolve your configuration directly into a class? Show us the code you use to work with typesafe config. A [MCVE] if you will.

Comment: @Yuval: Added the code as well

Comment: The path you're using is relative... Maybe you're not executing your app from the same place as before? Make a test and try to specify an absolute path, or if the file is in your classpath, try to specify it as a Resource instead of building a new File(path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
def loadConfig(filename: String, syntax: ConfigSyntax): Config = {
val in: InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream(filename)
if (in == null) return null
val file: File = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(in.hashCode()), ".conf")
file.deleteOnExit()

val out: FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)
val buffer: Array[Byte] = new Array(1024)
var bytesRead: Int = in.read(buffer)
while (bytesRead != -1) { out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); bytesRead = in.read(buffer) }
out.close()

val conf: Config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(file, ConfigParseOptions.defaults().setSyntax(syntax).setAllowMissing(false).setOriginDescription("Merged with " + filename))
conf
```

}

filename is some file path ***in the classpath***. If you want to update this method to taking some external file into account, change update the 4th with `val file: File = new File("absolute Path of he file")`

Comment: This Project is in IntelliJ Workspace. I am using mavne to take the build. The build is not taking the latest updated conf file. It takes the previous version of conf file .

Comment: I can't help you with IntelliJ, I'm an eclipse user... With eclipse, it can happen when you're dealing with projects you built out of eclipse (this includes the Run as Maven build from eclipse IDE). I suppose something like that can happen with IntelliJ. Try to delete your builds from ${user}/.m2/repository/your-groupId/* and rerun your test. It should take your workspace project into account instead of any installed version into mvn local repo. But well, it's an eclipse tip, I don't know if it works with intelliJ...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the file isn't on the classpath after you build with Maven.

Since you are using Maven to build a jar, you need your `omega.config` to be in the classpath. This means that you either have to put it into `src/main/resources` by default or explicitly tell Maven to add `conf` to the default resources classpath.